# Automatic change in data type when reopening CSV file

Tags: excel, csv, types, google-bigquery, format

After changing Data type of column from General or Number to Text and saving as CSV file (column has Numbers only). When you reopen the file the data type is getting changed back to General automatically.
How to stop it getting changed automatically ? I need the change made in CSV file format for uploading to big query.
Thanks.

I tried VBA, data transformation in excel, Text function, Putting ' in front of number, Text to Columns option.

Comment: CSV files do not include any formatting information. In **Excel**, if you want to set a particular data type, you should not **OPEN** the file, Better to **IMPORT** the file using either `Power Query` or the legacy wizard. In `BigQuery` (with which I have no experience) the documentation suggests you specify a **schema** which will probably do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

CSV has no data type but you can bigquery load with schema

[load with schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas)

ex using bq load with schema string

```
bq load --source_format=CSV mydataset.mytable ./myfile.csv schema:STRING,string:FLOAT
```

or with schema file

```
bq load --source_format=CSV mydataset.mytable ./myfile.csv schema.json
```